# Hadron composition

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks

I have been reading a lot about the differentiation of "valence" quarks versus "sea" or "virtual" quarks in the composition of hadrons.

My question is if there is any evidence of all families of quarks contributing to the "sea" within any paricular hadron, or must they only be "virtual" versions of the physical "valence" quarks we can "observe" in current experimentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual quarks are all kinds. The strange quark singlet anomalous magnetic moment in the proton has been measured, for example.  See the SAMPLE experiment https://bateslab.mit.edu/projects/sample